# how to insert line break after a specific string?

Tags: unix, awk, sed, terminal, scripting

I have a file with the following text, I want to make a line break, after the `S.` character

i have  this

```
1900-01-01 00:00:00|1|S|S|S|S.1900-01-01|S.1900-01-01 00:00:00|1|S|S|S|S.1900-01-01 00:00:00|1|S|S|S|S.
```

i want

```
1900-01-01 00:00:00|1|S|S|S|S.
1900-01-01|S.
1900-01-01 00:00:00|1|S|S|S|S.
1900-01-01 00:00:00|1|S|S|S|S.
```

i tried this

```
$ sed 's/S./\n/g' file.csv > file2.csv
```

Comment: **much** better question, to make it complete just add at the bottom a statement that starts with `but...` to explain in what way what you tried failed to satisfy your requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With any sed that accepts `\n` as meaning "newline":

```
$ sed 's/S\./&\n/g' file
1900-01-01 00:00:00|1|S|S|S|S.
1900-01-01|S.
1900-01-01 00:00:00|1|S|S|S|S.
1900-01-01 00:00:00|1|S|S|S|S.
```

or in bash for `$'\n'` to get a newline char:

```
$ sed 's/S\./&\'$'\n''/g' file
1900-01-01 00:00:00|1|S|S|S|S.
1900-01-01|S.
1900-01-01 00:00:00|1|S|S|S|S.
1900-01-01 00:00:00|1|S|S|S|S.
```

or portably with any sed in any shell:

```
$ sed 's/S\./&\
/g' file
1900-01-01 00:00:00|1|S|S|S|S.
1900-01-01|S.
1900-01-01 00:00:00|1|S|S|S|S.
1900-01-01 00:00:00|1|S|S|S|S.
```

Note that the output will end in a blank line since the script adds a newline after **every** `S.` as requested. If you actually only want to add a newline after every `S.` mid-line then that'd be:

```
$ sed 's/\(S\.\)\(.\)/\1\n\2/g' file
1900-01-01 00:00:00|1|S|S|S|S.
1900-01-01|S.
1900-01-01 00:00:00|1|S|S|S|S.
1900-01-01 00:00:00|1|S|S|S|S.
```

Comment: both scripts return `1900-01-01 00:00:00|1|S|S|S|S.n1900-01-01|S.n1900-01-01 00:00:00|1|S|S|S|S.n1900-01-01 00:00:00|1|S|S|S|S.` add `n`

Comment: I said `With any sed that accepts \n as meaning "newline:`. The sed you're running obviously doesn't and so treats `\n` as a literal `n` character. I'll add the portable version.

Comment: Done. I added workarounds for seds that don't understand `\n` that'll work in bash or any shell.

Comment: `sed 's/S\./&\'$'\n''/g' file` this work perfecly, thank

Comment: You're welcome but you should always give it a few hours to see what answers you get rather than just accepting the first answer posted that produces the output you expect since there may be better answers possible. Getting the output you expect from the sample input you provided is the starting point to identifying a solution, not the end point.

Answer (score 1):

When each line in the file has a `S.` combination, you can use a non-greedy pattern

```
grep -oP ".*?S[.]" file
```

When you can have different lines, you need to add an alternative

```
grep -oP ".*?S[.]|.*" file
```

Answer (score 0):

if data in `d` file, tried on gnu sed:

```
sed -E 's/S\./&\n/g' d
```

Comment: That's exactly the same as the first script in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55839646/1745001). You don't need the `-E` as there's nothing in that regexp that requires EREs.

Answer (score 0):

In git bash under windows, this:

```
 sed 's/S\./S\.\n/g' input-file // replace 'S.' with 'S.new-line'
```

worked perfectly.
I used it to reformat some text files.